# The set of points where derivative converges

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, convergence-divergence

I have a given function $f(x)$ which is a series of polynomials and a set $\{x\in \mathbb{R} | f(x)$converges$\}$. I have calculated the derivative $f'(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n^2(x-1)^{n-1}$, but how can I determine the set of points where the derivative converges?

Comment: We need more information please.

Comment: I have edited the post now

Answer (score 0):

It is highly likely you assumed that derivative converged uniformly when calculating it. In any case, this is the second derivative of a geometric series thus converges whenever $|x-1|\lt 1$. Since it is a Taylor series, it converges uniformly on this disc. Obviously the nth term does not tend to zero when $x=2,-1$ does not converge at these boundary points. Therefore the derivative converges precisely when $|x-1|\lt 1$